# Quote Line item to a custom object

Tags: custom-object, quote

I have custom object where I am storing my product information. Now I want to set up a quote for the product. But when we create quote line item I need to add the records from custom product object not from standard product object. Is it possible, please help me how can I use my custom product with the standard quote.

Comment: It will all have to be custom development and is too broad for the venue

Comment: Hi @Eric you mean if I have a custom product in the place of standard product then I need to have all the qoute, pricebook etc should be custom object. Can you explain more.

Comment: Yes Anu, all the standard functionality is hard-wired to the standard objects. Most of that doesn't work when you start using custom objects for part of the process. You'll have to do everything custom. I'd recommend you do try to use the standard product object.